# Ensime configuration for scala library

Tags: scala, emacs, jar, ensime

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import scalaj.http.Http
Http("http://foo.com/search").param("q","monkeys").asString
```

I am getting a red bar inside emacs at line 1, which I believe is ensime telling me that it couldn't find the imported library, how do I tell ensime that I want it to recognize a jar? I've tried adding the path to the jar in `:compile-deps` and `:runtime-deps` in my `.ensime` but without success.

I am using emacs-snapshot-gtk (v24.3.50.1) along with ensime 0.1.1.

This is my `build.sbt`, placed at the root of my project:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

retrieveManaged := true

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.7"
```

Comment: Did you use the ensime sbt plugin (https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime-sbt-cmd) to generate your `.ensime` config?